# I solved the Cipher, why did the hack fail anyway?

Tags: warframe

I have failed hacking a Cipher two times even though I solved the pattern like this:

[image]

Why did it fail when it looks solved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NOTE: This was fixed in Update 11**

The reason is because the center tile is not placed correct.

Even though it looks solved the center tile actually needs to be turned 180° for it to be solved.

3 fast clicks on the center tile will solve the Cipher for you.

Comment: That looks like a bad design flaw; the background doesn't even give you a proper clue.

Comment: If you look closely it's misaligned, but yes it's not great design. There should be a portion of the centerpiece that doesn't connect to one of the outer tiles.

Comment: Meh. When it's solved, it gives you visual and auditory feedback so you know. It not being solved when it "looks" solved is to increase the level of difficulty of the puzzle-solving without making it impossible. This is just another trick you learn as you master the game. I don't believe it is a design flaw.

Comment: @Blem this was fixed with Update 14. Took 'em a full year to fix it.